# Is a specific thread inside the threading.enumerate()?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I need to check if an specific thread is inside the results of `threading.enumerate()`.

Let's suppose I get the results with the enumerate:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 8568)>
<Thread(Thread-263, started 11116)>
<MyThread(Thread-235, started 21045)>
```

How can I check that the Thread `MyThread` is inside my results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter on class of thread:

```
>>> import threading
>>> class MyThread(threading.Thread): pass
...
>>> def do_nothing():
...     while True:
...         pass

>>> MyThread(target=do_nothing).start()
>>> threading.Thread(target=do_nothing).start()
>>> threading.enumerate()
[<MyThread(Thread-1, started 8040)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 7352)>, <_MainThread(MainThread, started 2772)>]
>>> [t for t in threading.enumerate() if isinstance(t, MyThread)]
[<MyThread(Thread-1, started 8040)>]
```